# Twitter API Rate Limit: Does it increase for my app if if 1 year ago users authorized my app?

Tags: twitter, sttwitterapi

So I'm trying to figure out if Twitter increases the rate limit for my app if I had users sign-in - and keeps the rate increase - even if users signed in 1 year ago.  Meaning, does just the act of signing in increase the pool your app is allowed of requests?  And what am I using if this is so, the app token without using the user token? Does the app token "benefit". Of if I have 10 users from a year ago with 150 requests allowed per 15 minutes, to make use of the 1500 requests, would I only be able to 'get it' if user token is included with the request?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Twitter.com page on rate limits...](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting)

> Rate limiting of the API is primarily on a per-user basis — or more
>   accurately described, per user access token. If a method allows for 15
>   requests per rate limit window, then it allows 15 requests per window
>   per access token.

Each user/token gets their own allocation of requests; there's not a single set of requests shared by all users.